# Action-angle differential forms on the $2$-torus

Tags: complex-numbers, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields

> Consider the $2$-torus $\mathbb{T}^2 = S^1 \times S^1$, viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$, endowed with the product manifold smooth structure. Define the following vector fields on $\mathbb{T}^2:$ $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}\right)_{(z_1, z_2)} = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t = 0}  (e^{it} \cdot z_1, z_2) $$ and $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_2}\right)_{(z_1, z_2)} = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t = 0}  (z_1, e^{it} \cdot z_2), $$ for every $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{T}^2$.
>
> Now, we can see that these two vector fields are smooth. Moreover, these two vector fields form a basis for the tangent space $T_{(z_1, z_2)}(\mathbb{T}^2)$, for every $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{T}^2$. Hence, we can talk about their dual basis in $T^*(\mathbb{T}^2)$. Call those differential $1$-forms $d\theta_1$ and $d\theta_2$. We immediately see that for every $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$, we have that $$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_1} d\theta_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_2} d\theta_2. $$

It is not difficult to show that the $1$-forms $d\theta_1$ and $d\theta_2$ are not exact, since the differential of every smooth real-valued function defined on a compact manifold must vanish. It is also easy to see that those two $1$-forms are closed, and that $d\theta_2 \wedge d\theta_1$ is a volume form on $\mathbb{T}^2$. My question is the following:

> How to we compute the volume of $\mathbb{T}^2$, with respect to the volume form $d\theta_2 \wedge d\theta_1$, i.e. how do we compute $$\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} d\theta_2 \wedge d\theta_1. $$

I've always seen this integration on manifolds (without the use of the theorem of Stokes) as only theoretical, because in order to compute the above integral, we firstly need a finite cover of $\mathbb{T}^2$ with coordinate charts, then we need to integrate the the pullback of $d\theta_2 \wedge d\theta_1$ through every chart and so on.

How do we find the answer in this case? I don't know how to apply the theorem of Stokes here, since I would firstly need to determine what submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ has $S^1 \times S^1$ as its boundary. But even if I would be able to do that, the differential of $d\theta_2 \wedge d\theta_1$ is $0$, but the volume cannot be zero.

Comment: Do you know how to find $\int_{S^1}d\theta$? Use Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: How would Fubini's theorem help in this case? And no, I don't know how to compute the integral you proposed.

Comment: Parametrize the circle (except for one point) and pull back and integrate. Or work it out in $xy$-coordinates. Fubini applies because the torus is globally a product.

Comment: I don't know if we are talking about the same Fubini's theorem. Do you mean the standard Fubini's theorem for integrals on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$, or is there a different theorem for product manifolds?

Comment: I mean Fubini for the product of measure spaces. But all we need here is the fact that we can compute the double integral as an iterated integral, and because we're on a product manifold (and the function we're integrating is quite simple), that results in a product of integrals. You don't have to be so fancy. Parametrize all but a set of measure zero of the torus by two intervals. ... BTW, the "standard" orientation on the torus would want you to write $d\theta_1\wedge d\theta_2$.

Comment: I see now what you meant, thank you!